# How can I use dialog box in the mask editor to make my constant change?

Tags: matlab, callback, simulink

I have a simple block.

[image: Simple Block]

I create a mask using this block.
[image: Using mask I have this]

Then I edit the mask using popup. Now i have 2 choices. Sin or Cos.

[image: Editing mask using dialog box]

[image: Mask]

This is where it gets complicated.  I want my block which I called as 'Result' in the constant block is equal to 1 if i chose sin and , 0 if I chose answer as cos. I tried to write a callback function but I couldnt  do it. 
I am kinda new to these staff. Hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 problems:

1. You do not want your variable to be evaluated, so you need to de-select that option in the Mask Editor.
2. You do not want to call your variable `Result`.  At present your mask has `Result` being a string (either `sin` or `cos`), but the model expects `Result` to be a numeric value.  Let's assume you change the mask to create a variable called `fcn_selected` instead.
3. You have not shown us your callback code, nor told us where you put the code.

For 3. you want to write code something like

```
switch fcn_selected
   case 'Sin'
      Result = 1;
   case 'Cos'
      Result = 0;
end
```

And you want to put the code on the Mask Editor's `Initialization` pane.